# HTML list break

Tags: html, css

I'm working on an online shop right now, and I have some problems with listing featured categories. After resizing of featured categories (first on home page), it was only 3 categories and it was perfect, now when I added the fourth category, it breaks.
I will post link of website here, it is online shop but you can't buy from it, so it's not advertisement.

Link: https://ecomet.co/

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a look at [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and rework your question.

Comment: please provide some code so we can help.

Comment: To preserve your questions long-term value, your code should be *in the question*, not linked.  What happens to your question once your websites code is updated or goes down?

Answer (score 0):

As I found from your code you created a separate `<div class="row">` for your forth category that's why its shows below.

Add all four category inside one bootstrap 'row' class. i.e :

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">1st category</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">2st category</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">3st category</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">4st category</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like you updated your code in your project, does my solution help you?